# Angular 2 - How to route to a new page without showing the html in app.component.html in the new page

Tags: html, angular, routes, angular2-routing

I just have a general question. I know how to route between pages, but `app.component.html` is always shown on the top of the page every single time I go to a new page. I want to know how to stop showing `app.component.html` on a couple of pages. I'm creating kind of a restaurant web page as a project and I want the navigation bar to show on most pages, but some pages don't require it.
I'm currently using `app.routing.ts` to import the components and
`const appRoutes: Routes = []` to set the path of the pages.
If possible, I'd like a typescript answer but I can try and understand javascript

Comment: It depend if your <router-outlet></router-outlet> is into it or not

Comment: my router-outlet is inside my app.component.html.
does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use routerLink and router-outlet to do the navigation bar.

```
<div>
    <a [routerLink]='place/index'>index</a>
    <a [routerLink]='place/info'>info</a>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And you can setup the routes to your module.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path:'index',component: IndexComponent}
])
```

The IndexComponent served the path /place/index.

Comment: Thanks neuropaddy, but that's just how to do normal routing. I have the same code  implemented, but when I go into a new page, whatever I have in my app.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'mw-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
is shown on every page. I want to see if I can remove app.component.ts from appearing in certain pages. Thanks though!

Comment: May be you can refer to the above link, observe navigate event and disable the div that you don't want. This may be a method to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider two components home and login which has two different layouts, in that case, create two components using the command
 `ng g c layouts/home-layout -s -t` and  `ng g c layouts/login-layout -s -t` which creates a two components (-t inline template -s inline style). Once this is done in **app.component.html** keep only **router-outlet**. Then in **home-layout.component.ts** in the template section design your layout

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-layout',
  template: `
  <app-headding></app-headding>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <app-menu></app-menu>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class HomeLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

similarly, create login layout without menu selector

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-layout',
  template: `
  <app-headding></app-headding>
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class LoginLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Now set up the routing module by creating child components to these modules

```
import { LoginLayoutComponent } from './layouts/login-layout/login-layout.component';
import { HomeLayoutComponent } from './layouts/home-layout/home-layout.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'create-repo', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '', component: HomeLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
    ]
  },
  {path: '', component: LoginLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
    ]
  },
  {path: '**', component: CreateRepoComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I hope it helps someone.